# How to add a random limit in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I can `SELECT` a random number between 0 and 1000 by doing:

```
SELECT ROUND((RAND()*1000))
-- 931
```

However, why I try and do that in a limit I get a error:

```
...LIMIT ROUND((RAND()*1000))
```

> Undeclared variable: round

Why does this error occur? Is these another way to do a random limit like this in mysql?

Comment: What mysql version?

Comment: @danblack 5.7 --

Comment: The parameters to `LIMIT` have to be constants, they can't be expressions.

Comment: You may generate a dynamic query, that way you can place the randomly generated limit in the query as a constant.

Comment: @Barmar Not constant. Literal. See prepared statement - LIMIT/OFFSET may be a parameter.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for that. Out of curiosity, why does mysql implement that design-wise? Do most other DB systems do the same?

Comment: @David542 `LIMIT` is not a standard SQL feature -- every DBMS has different ways to limit the number of returned records (e.g. SQL-Server uses `SELECT TOP n ...`). I don't know whether the others require the value to be a literal. But MySQL has lots of silly restrictions like this.